# TCL/TK widget::dateentry textvariable problem. When I change the text variable the widget does not change

Tags: datepicker, widget, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have this simple TCL/TK code to test date picker widget. If I click the widget I can change the date value and widget is updated correctly. However, when I want to set a start-up value to something else widget is not updated at all.

```
package require widget::dateentry

console show
set ::DATE ""
set start [widget::dateentry .s -textvariable ::START_DATE -dateformat "%d/%m/%Y" -firstday sunday]
set end [widget::dateentry   .e -textvariable ::END_DATE   -dateformat "%d/%m/%Y" -firstday sunday]
grid [label .sl -text "Start:"] $start  -padx 4 -pady 4
grid [label .el -text "End:"  ] $end    -padx 4 -pady 4

set ::START_DATE 01/01/2023
set ::END_DATE   31/12/2023
```

[image]

Executing the following code from the wish console does not have any effect on the widget:

```
set ::START_DATE 01/01/2023
set ::END_DATE   31/12/2023
```

Variable value changed, however widget does NOT. Both widgets still show today's date. Please can someone help how to set textvariable START_DATE and END_DATE see the widget updated as expected?

Thank you
Daniel

Comment: Looks like that's just not implemented. There's no trace being set to monitor that variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an entirely unimplemented feature when I look through [the source](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tklib/file?name=modules/widget/dateentry.tcl&ci=tip); there are no calls to `trace add variable` in that code, nor is the contents of the `-textvariable` option passed to anything else likely-looking. I think this is surprising and a bug. I've filed [this](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tklib/tktview/832099c71568633551b742440525bd99b3db7a0b) issue about it.

Comment: Hello Donal,

please can you send me a code to fix it if you know how to do it. I guess a new method has to be written. Unfortunately I have no experience with this. Perhaps there is a workaround. Regards

Comment: The problem is that there's external and internal state models, and changes to the external model (the `-textvariable`) aren't being pushed to the internal model (an internal Tcl variable in a Snit object). I don't know whether simply adding appropriate traces would be sufficient. I'm not a tklib developer so reporting it is the best I can do quickly.